# Many-to-many mapping from multiple entities

Tags: symfony

I have an Asset entity, and I want multiple other entities (let's say Product and Page) to have many-to-many relations to Asset, **without** having multiple tables (product_asset, page_asset).

The reason I want this is because want to simply display all assets, without first having to find all entities that have a relation to the Asset entity.

The [Translatable Doctrine Extension](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions) is a perfect example of what I mean. There's one Translation entity containing an ObjectClass property that stores object's class name. I've been looking through to code for some time now, but just can't seem to figure out how they actually make it work.

So concrete, how can I map entities based on their class name like the Translatable Extension does? To have a structure like this:

```
|----|--------------------|----------|-----------|
| id | objectClass        | objectId | value     |
|----|--------------------|----------|-----------|
| 1  | App\Entity\Product | 1        | test.jpg  |
| 2  | App\Entity\Page    | 1        | test2.png |
| 3  | App\Entity\Page    | 2        | test3.gif |
|----|--------------------|----------|-----------|
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you have a misunderstanding somewhere. If you want *all* assets (independent of any objects), you can just `$em->getRepository(Asset::class)->findAll()`. Don't see, why multiple or single many-to-many makes a difference here ...

Comment: keyword: single table inheritance: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

Comment: also the attribute/mapping overrides.

Comment: Getting all the assets isn't the problem, the thing is that I want to be able to do `$product->getAssets()` and `$page->getAssets()`. I came across Single Table Inheritance too, but then you'll have to define every entity in Asset using the DiscriminatorMap annotation, but Asset is located in a custom vendor bundle I've created, so it never knows which entities will be using it beforehand.

Comment: why exactly do you want to avoid multiple many-to-many join tables? can you elaborate? because I have this weird feeling you're trying to solve a problem that's not apparent and ask for a solution that might or might not even be necessary or advisable.

Comment: btw: how is your asset defined, via a "value" that is the filename or does it have an id? because your imagined table structure seems to imply that.

Comment: if you're wondering how Translatable handles this: it "magically" adds a join **for every single translatable field** in a query. which is, in that case, like multiple 1:1 joins, although the table it uses looks like k:l.n:m (dimensions: objecttype:objectid:field:locale) have a look at: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Query/TreeWalker/TranslationWalker.php . I find that quite messy. you lose almost all benefits of a relational database (that is specifically: foreign keys and integrity checks)

Comment: Yeah indeed, there are no "real" relations in there, but I thought maybe Doctrine had something more "clean" to make it work like that. Thanks for the help anyway, you actually made me realize that I have to stop focussing on putting everything in one table, and create a better solution, maybe by using traits or something :-)

Comment: my advice is: just do classic many-to-many associations and be done with it. this is probably the best solution, if assets are shared. if they're not shared, it's still a good solution. (one-to-many might be slightly better, because it requires one less join). but I absolutely get your sentiment ... Don't Repeat Yourself and stuff. I probably would have thought about "saving" the effort too.